# Замінник слова "атмосферний"

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, калька

На телебаченні часто можна почути слово "атмосферний", в значенні той, що викликає певні емоції, відчуття. Та в українських словниках відсутнє дане тлумачення цього слова, лише подане [таке](http://sum.in.ua/s/atmosfernyj) - який виникає, відбувається в атмосфері. Хоча в тлумаченні слова ["атмосфера"](http://sum.in.ua/s/atmosfera) є таке значення -  умови, обстановка, породжувані соціальним середовищем, колективом, родиною і т. ін. Тому й такий же ж прикметник в значенні *той, що заставляє нас зануритись в певну атмосферу* також, на мою думку, має право існувати. В російській мові присутні обидва значення слова ["атмосферний"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9). Тоді можливо вживання даного прикметника в українській мові в значенні, той що викликає певні емоції, неправильно і є калькою з російської? Яке слово краще вжити замість нього?

Answer (score 3):

Не думаю, що "атмосферний" може бути калькою з російської, оскільки це прикметник, утворений від іменника, що пішов з грецької мови.

[image: атмосфера]

Але у разі, якщо ви хочете використати слово синонімічне, то, мабуть, [*душевний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/dushevnyj) підходить під ваш опис:

> //  Який викликає приємні почуття, приємно вражає. [Ярина:] Ох, як я люблю душевні пісні (Олександр Корнійчук, II, 1955, 101); Почула, що чергує Артем Громов, і одразу її голос пом'якшав, помолодів, таким душевним став (Василь Кучер, Чорноморці, 1956, 28).

Comment: Чому не думајете, коли тут прьамо пишуть _запозичене через московську_? Відти ж бо могли запозичити _атмосферниј_ в јакости не науковојі тьамки, а _јакихось почуттьів_,

Answer (score 3):

Також може підійти за значенням слово "[чуттєвий](http://sum.in.ua/s/chuttjevyj)":

> 1. Здійснюваний за допомогою органів чуття. Розуміння зароджується вже в чуттєвому сприйманні людиною навколишньої дійсності (Радянська психологічна наука.., 1958, 142); Чуттєве сприймання музики найтісніше зв'язане з її осмисленням (Мистецтво, 2, 1968, 23);
>
>    // рідко. Те саме, що чутливий 1. [Платон:] Пальці хірурга мусять бути такі ж розроблені, гнучкі і чуттєві, як пальці скрипаля чи піаніста (Олександр Корнійчук, I, 1955, 99);
>
>    // Стос. до чуття, пов'язаний з ним; душевний. Наш чуттєвий світ, звичайно, невіддільний від споконвічного прагнення до щастя і від того, наскільки це прагнення плідне (Радянське літературознавство, 11, 1965, 3). 
>      ▲ Чуттєвий досвід, філос. — сукупність сприйнять органами чуття, що набувається в процесі взаємодії людини з зовнішньою природою і становить основу всіх наших знань про матеріальний світ.
> 2. Пов'язаний із задоволенням тілесного потягу. Чуттєва насолода.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти.